# Java - Get first and last name of user

Tags: java, windows, macos

Here is my situation.

I am writing a program that will store a database. Currently, the way of identifying the user is by their computer user name. I am very desperate here, so any ideas will work. I am looking for ANY method (doesn't always need to work) for BOTH OSX and Windows computers that will somehow fetch the user's first and last name.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Yes. I am aware of this and have a solution ready. I am just looking for people to pitch out some ideas and code. When I said the BOTH part, I meant like some different methods for both OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times, the computer won't even *know* the user's real name -- you realize that, right? That said, there's a Java system property "user.name" which will always contain the login name, on any system:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

That's the only thing you can get with any reliability.

... except for *prompting* the user. Why not just ask them for their name?

Comment: Yes. This is what I currently have. I am looking for any ways that could improve this.

Comment: I am afraid that some users will not put their real name in. This is why I am requesting that I have a way or two to double check ...

Comment: You need to require some internal or external identity that you trust, such as LDAP, ActiveDirectory, etc. Of course under the right circumstances those can be spoofed too. Provide the SPECIFIC user case, and detail how acceptable security violations are. (they always occur, so don't answer unacceptable)